# AWS Websocket API - how to pass data passed with route and further pass the same data to http integration endpoint in url path

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

[image: AWS sendmessage route image]

My integration to http endpoint is working fine , but not able to figure out how i can pass data in endpoint url

I am sending data like {"action":"sendmessage", "data":"mydata123"} to Websocket API and it is  calling the http endpoint , now i want to send mydata123 as endpoint path like -https://bblbackendapi.azurewebsites.net/api/users/mydata123

[image: Integration Request screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be achieved with Integration type as "HTTP", i changed Integration type as "Lambda Function" and did it. Realized that it is the best way to use Lambda's as we have full control over any type of customization we want.